Using terraform - connect cloud_build to existing private postgres
I intend to make migrations from cloud build to cloud_sql postgres which is in private network.
using terraform create google_cloudbuild_worker_pool and connect to existing postgres cloud_sql in existing private google_compute_network vpn_network.
I have already created VPC. I need to create worker pool to allow connection between cloud build and postgress.
If I try creating cloud_build_worker_pool in existing vpc as shown below - I get error:
# CloudBuild worker example from terraform
resource "google_project_service" "servicenetworking" {
  service = "servicenetworking.googleapis.com"
  disable_on_destroy = false
}

resource "google_compute_global_address" "worker_range" {
  name          = "worker-pool-range"
  purpose       = "VPC_PEERING"
  address_type  = "INTERNAL"
  prefix_length = 16
  network       = google_compute_network.vpc_network.id
}

resource "google_service_networking_connection" "worker_pool_conn" {
  network                 = google_compute_network.vpc_network.id
  service                 = "servicenetworking.googleapis.com"
  reserved_peering_ranges = [google_compute_global_address.worker_range.name]
  depends_on              = [google_project_service.servicenetworking]
}

resource "google_cloudbuild_worker_pool" "pool" {
  name = var.cb_private_pool_name
  location = var.region

  network_config {
    peered_network = google_compute_network.vpc_network.id
    peered_network_ip_range = "/29"
  }
  depends_on = [google_service_networking_connection.worker_pool_conn]
}

Error:
Error: Error waiting for Create Service Networking Connection: Error code 9, message: Cannot modify allocated ranges in CreateConnection. Please use UpdateConnection. │ Help Token: asdasd │  │   with module.vpc_connector.google_service_networking_connection.worker_pool_conn, │   on ../modules/vpc_connector/main.tf line 153, in resource "google_service_networking_connection" "worker_pool_conn": │  153: resource "google_service_networking_connection" "worker_pool_conn" {
